MERGE STATEMENT (T-SQL) not inserting any row, throwing error saying identity insert not allowed
I have built a MERGE statement to insert and update a dimension table (Customer) which has an identity column shown in this table structure:
-- Create the table in the specified schema
CREATE TABLE [dim].[customer_crm]
(
    [customer_skey] INT identity (1,1), -- Primary Key column
    customer_number nvarchar(100) NULL,
    customer_name NVARCHAR(450) NULL,
    customer_address NVARCHAR(500) NULL,
    post_code nvarchar (150) NULL,
    state nvarchar ( 150 ) NULL,
    country nvarchar ( 100) NULL,
    ABN nvarchar (100) NULL,
    contact_no nvarchar(50) NULL,
    email nvarchar(200) NULL,
    is_parent varchar(4) NULL,
    parent_customer_number varchar (10) NULL,
    dw_insert_timestamp DATETIME NULL
    -- Specify more columns here
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( customer_number ),  --(hash distributed table on this Id column)
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)

This is my MERGE statement:
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dim.customer_crm on
GO

MERGE INTO dim.customer_crm AS tgt
USING (SELECT 
           accountnumber, name, 
           ISNULL(address1_line1, '') + ',' + ISNULL(address1_line2, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(address2_city,'') AS address,   
           LEFT(address1_postalcode, 5) AS post_code, 
           address1_stateorprovince, address2_country AS country, 
           emailaddress1 AS email, new_abn AS abn, telephone1 AS telephone,
           CASE WHEN parentaccountid IS NULL THEN 'n' ELSE 'y' END AS is_parent
       FROM
           src.crm_account a
       WHERE 
           statuscode = 1) src ON (tgt.customer_number = src.accountnumber)
        
   WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
            UPDATE 
            SET 
                customer_number = src.accountnumber,
                customer_name = src.Name,
                customer_address = src.address,
                post_code = src.post_code,
                country = src.country,
                email = src.email,
                abn = src.abn,
                contact_no = src.telephone,
                is_parent = src.is_parent                             

    WHEN NOT MATCHED
        THEN
            INSERT (customer_number, customer_name, customer_address, post_code, country, email, abn, contact_no, is_parent   )
            VALUES (src.accountnumber, src.name, src.address, src.post_code, src.country, src.email, src.abn, src.telephone, src.is_parent );


SET IDENTITY_INSERT dim.customer_crm off

However this does not insert any rows, and throwing an error:

Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot update identity column 'customer_skey'.

The Customer_skey is not part of the MERGE statement and it is an identity column.
Please help to fix this why it is not working even though Customer_skey is not part of the MERGE update statement.

If that column is not in your merge, then its most likely in a trigger.

@DaleK please elaborate bit more where exactly an issue is?

Not really, if you're not familiar with triggers I suggest doing some online reading.

I think this is a bug in merge statement, at least it looks familiar. Don't use merge and everyone will be happier anyway https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1138652/cannot-update-identity-column-rowid-in-synapse-sql

Yeah why are you turning identity insert on if you aren't inserting an identity?

I believe you have the IDENTITY_INSERT settings backwards.  ON means that you intend to explicitly provide the identity value. OFF (the default) means that you don't provide the value and its value is automatically assigned.  See this db<>fiddle.  I get a different error message though - "Explicit value must be specified for identity column..."

@TN - The OP is on Synapse (DISTRIBUTION = HASH) - so the link siggemannen gave explains it. MERGE WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT just doesn't work for tables with identity columns

Shame OP didn't think to tell us the exact database they are using

You can remove the following and try:
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dim.customer_crm on
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dim.customer_crm off


SET IDENTITY_INSERT dim.customer_crm on
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dim.customer_crm off, after removing the issue is same. this was included due the error after reading many post. but I now removed as it does not make sense to include this as I am not inserting any record to identity column

@siggemannen, it is correct as this is known bug. sad as I used to developed many MARGE statement over the past on SQL server.
